# Cylinder Target + Video playback on vuforia ios

Tags: ios, native, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm going to make an Augmented Reality app using Vuforia for ios on which there's a soda can as a target, then if you scan the target using the app, a video will play. So I'm going to use the Cylinder Target and Video Playback features. Is it possible to combine those 2 features? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any problem - playing a video is what you do (in OpenGL) once a target was identified. There's no conflict here.

Comment: another question. Can I scan multiple objects simultaneously? Thanks

Comment: Yes, multiple target detection is supported in Vuforia - but the best thing is to read the exact limitations on Vuforia's documentation.

Comment: I've read that maximum object target detection is only 2.. do you know other AR libraries or sdks which can scan multiple objects simultaneously? Thanks again.

Comment: Not all SDKs have this feature at all, and Vuforia is considered one of the best. Anyway, what you can do is look for SDKs marked with the feature  '3D Object Tracking' at this AR SDKs comparison here: http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks